# Get all markers in Google Maps v3 Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer, jquery-ui-map

Google Maps v3 JQuery introduced the following way to get markers:

```
$map.gmap('get', 'markers');
```

I'm trying this, but getting an empty array. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
var smap = $('#smap');  

$(window).load(function() {
    /* Initialize Map */
    smap.gmap({
        center: '34.913167, -94.618089',
        zoom: 5
    }).bind('init', function() {
        /* Add markers */
        $.getJSON('static/stninfo.js', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, stn) {
                var latlng = (stn.loc).substring(0, stn.loc.length - 4);

                smap.gmap('addMarker', {
                    position: latlng,
                    bounds: false,
                    id: stn.stnid
                }).click(function() {
                    smap.gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                        content: '<strong>' + stn.name + '</strong></br>' + latlng
                    }, this); 
                });
            });
        });

        var imap = smap.gmap('get', 'map');
        var imarkers = smap.gmap('get', 'markers');

        console.log(imap);
        console.log(smap.gmap('get', 'markers'));
        /* Initialize clusters */
        smap.gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(imap, imarkers));

    });
});
```

As per the code, I need this to use the MarkerClusterer. I'm not getting any errors in the console. As to the results of the `console.log`s, the first one (imap) returns the map object correctly. The second (marker list) simply returns an empty array ("[]").

It appears there's nothing wrong with the MarkerClusterer code; my suspicion is I'm adding the markers incorrectly. Any insight on what's wrong here?

I've been using this as a reference: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.getJSON is async, when console.log(smap.gmap('get', 'markers')); executes getJSON probably hasn't ended yet, so there's your empty array.

put it inside the getjson code and most probably you'll get it working

```
       $.getJSON('static/stninfo.js', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, stn) {
            var latlng = (stn.loc).substring(0, stn.loc.length - 4);

            smap.gmap('addMarker', {
                position: latlng,
                bounds: false,
                id: stn.stnid
            }).click(function() {
                smap.gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                    content: '<strong>' + stn.name + '</strong></br>' + latlng
                }, this); 
            });
        });
        console.log(smap.gmap('get', 'markers'));
    });
```

Comment: Oh gosh, can't believe that slipped past me. I tip my hat to you. Now I need to figure out why my MarkerClusterer STILL isn't working.